# Does the empty word count as a 'word'?

Tags: finite-automata

If I have DFA accepting

$\{w \in \{a,b\}^*$ s.t. on every odd position in $w$ there is a $b\}$

Would the empty word be accepted? Also, would the word $eb$ be accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty word belongs to the language, since on all its odd positions -- all zero of them -- we find a $b$.

$eb$ does not belong to $\{a,b\}^*$, hence it does not belong to the language.

Comment: Why does eb not belong to the language? Apologies if I wasn't clear, I'm denoting the empty word by e.

Comment: @Leonhard You can simply write it as $b$, then. In such case, it depends on whether "positions" start counting from 1 or from 0. I'd guess from 1 (but it really depends on the convention): if so, that $b$ does belong to the language.